# Reactjs router switch conflict

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used React router like code below but my `account` page return 404.

```
<Router>
            <Switch component={App}>
                <Route exact
                    path={CelestialSettings.path + 'account'}
                    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />} main={<Register />} sidebar={<Popular />} feature={<Featurex />} mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />
                <Route exact
                    path={CelestialSettings.path + 'posts/:slug'}
                    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />}
                        main={<Detail detailink={CelestialSettings.path + 'posts/:slug'} />}
                        sidebar={<Popular />}
                        feature={<Featurex />}
                        mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />
                <Route exact={true}
                    path={CelestialSettings.path + ':slug'}
                    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />}
                        main={<Page />}
                        sidebar={<Popular />}
                        feature={<Featurex />}
                        mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />
                <Route exact
                    path={CelestialSettings.path + 'category/:slug'}
                    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />} main={<Category />} sidebar={<Popular />} feature={<Featurex />} mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />

                <Route exact
                    path={CelestialSettings.path}
                    render={(props) => <App header={<Header />} main={<Blog add_category="" />} sidebar={<Popular />} feature={<Featurex />} mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />

                <Route render={(props) => <App header={<Header />} main={<NotFoundPage />} sidebar={<Popular />} feature={<Featurex />} mainbottom={<Categories />} />} />

            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Can everyone help me to check it?

Comment: which url isn't working correctly, also what is the value of CelestialSettings.path

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri CelestialSettings.path is just home url. URL http://localhost/website/account is not working

Comment: and is `CelestialSettings.path`  `/website/` or `/website` or `localhost/website`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri. It set like this var CelestialSettings = {"title":"My web","path":"\/website\/"}

Comment: ok, can you confirm and print `console.log(CelestialSettings.path + 'account')` in render method or check using react devtools that the Route path is being formed correctly

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it does not help. You think `CelestialSettings.path + 'account'` wrong? It is not wrong.

Comment: Based on your above code, that was the only reason I could think of. There may be something else wrong in your config, but its hard to tell from your current code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri However, thank you so much. I see problem. It is because of cache